# Store value from jsonEncode(PHP) into responseHandler and store it into variable

Tags: php, android, json

I had search many things but didn't work. So this is my problem.

I have succeed to make login form with responseHandler. This is the code :

```
  public void login()
  {
        httpClient=new DefaultHttpClient();
        httpPost= new HttpPost("http://studentstracking.hol.es/loginDatabase2.php");
        nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username",txtId.getText().toString().trim()));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password",txtPassword.getText().toString().trim()));

        httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
        response=httpClient.execute(httpPost);

        ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
        final String response = httpClient.execute(httpPost, responseHandler);
        System.out.println("Response : " + response);

        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                tv.setText("Response from PHP : " + response);
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });

        if(response.equalsIgnoreCase("User Found")){
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this,"Login Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });

            startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this, student_activity.class));
        }else{
            showAlert();
        }}
```

And this is the PHP code :

```
 $username = $_POST['username'];
 $password = $_POST['password'];
 $query_search = "select * from user2 where kode_user2 = '".$username."' AND password = '".$password."'";
 $query_exec = mysqli_query($conn, $query_search) or die(mysqli_error($conn));
 $rows = mysqli_num_rows($query_exec);
 if($rows == 0) { 
     echo "No Such User Found"; 
 }
 else  {
     echo "User Found"; 
 }
```

But this time i want to execute the PHP and get the value from it and store it into variable or maybe store it into SQLite.

This is the PHP code :

```
 $query_search1 = "SELECT `schedule`.`kode_schedule`,`schedule`.`kode_matkul`,`matakuliah`.`title`,`schedule`.`ruang`,`kelas`.`latitude`,`kelas`.`longitude`,`kelas`.`lantai`,`schedule`.`hari`,`schedule`.`jam` FROM schedule LEFT JOIN `u466318196_track`.`matakuliah` ON `schedule`.`kode_matkul` = `matakuliah`.`kode_matkul` LEFT JOIN `u466318196_track`.`kelas` ON `schedule`.`ruang` = `kelas`.`ruang` WHERE(( kode_schedule = 'sch0001'))";
 $query_exec1 = mysqli_query($conn, $query_search1) or die(mysqli_error($conn));


  while ($data2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query_exec1))
 {
     $response['length'][] = $data2;
 }

 print json_encode($response);
```

And the result of this json is :

```
{
   "length":
   [
      {
          "kode_schedule":"sch0001",
          "kode_matkul":"TIB01",
          "title":"Basis Data",
          "ruang":"501",
          "latitude":"-6.18861653446272",
          "longitude":"106.801122526546",
          "lantai":"5",
          "hari":"Selasa",
          "jam":"17:45:00"
      },          
      {
          "kode_schedule":"sch0001",
          "kode_matkul":"TIB02",
          "title":"Pemrograman Berorientasi Objek",
          "ruang":"LABB",
          "latitude":"-6.18864706134991",
          "longitude":"106.801161122636",
          "lantai":"5",
          "hari":"Selasa",
          "jam":"19:30:00"
       }
    ]
 }
```

So i want to store the "kode_schedule","kode_matkul",etc values into variable such as String or maybe string with arrays.

Please kindly help me.

Comment: use https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/ . i will parse the json to java object

Comment: I'm getting confused with github. Could you do in chat ?

Answer (score 0):

You are getting results in response string.

```
   JSONObject mainObject=new JSONObject(response);

        for(int i: 0 and 1){
        mainObject.getJSONArray("length").getJSONObject(i).getString("kode_schedule");
        mainObject.getJSONArray("length").getJSONObject(i).getString("kode_matkul");
}
```

use json method to access accordingly. Their are are so many tutorial to learn json parsing.

Comment: (Edit) Could u give me full code directly from my first column code ?

Comment: I am also a beginner but this my might help you. I have edited the answer